# How to make an infinite SMOOTH scrolling background in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is what I have done using AS3:

```
var BGround1:Background=new Background();
var BGround2:Background= Background();
stage.addChild(BGround1);
stage.addChild(BGround2);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll, false, 0, true);

function moveScroll(e:Event): void
{

     BGround1.x -= scrollSpeed; 
     BGround2.x -= scrollSpeed; 
     if(BGround1.x <= -BGround1.width)
     {
           BGround1.x =BGround2.x + BGround2.width;
     }
     else if(BGround2.x <= -BGround2.width)
     {
           BGround2.x = BGround1.x + BGround1.width;
     }

}
```

However, If I set `scrollSpeed` too high, the movement is not smooth. Is there any way to make a smooth animation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BitmapData is a bit more complicated, but can achieve what you want. BlitMask is another solution, and relatively simple. - http://www.greensock.com/blitmask/ I'm sure at it's core it's utilizing BitmapData. Stage3d etc is a step further, but a bit more involved.

Comment: Is this a mobile app ? If so, you also want to set your StageQuality to low. Also, is there anything on your background that is animating ? If so, an you have cacheAsBitmap set, it'll go even slower because it's recaching it every frame. Lastly how big are these backgrounds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hungry Hero](http://www.hungryherogame.com/) game has a smooth infinite scrolling background and it isn't framebound. The game is open source and the author has this [video tutorial](http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-5-parallax-background/) explaining how he achieved what you need.

Basically, each background layer has a scroll speed **parallaxDepth** (to achieve the parallax effect) and there is a variable to control the overall scrolling speed **_speed** (because the hero drinks coffee and the scroll speed increases).

Here is part of the code, but I recommend watching his video tutorial and browsing the source code on Github.

```
// overall speed
var _speed = 1;

bgLayer1 = new BgLayer(1);
bgLayer1.parallaxDepth = 0.02;
this.addChild(bgLayer1);

bgLayer3 = new BgLayer(3);
bgLayer3.parallaxDepth = 0.5;
this.addChild(bgLayer3);

private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    // Background 1 - Sky
    bgLayer1.x -= Math.ceil(_speed * bgLayer1.parallaxDepth);
    // Hero flying left
    if (bgLayer1.x > 0) bgLayer1.x = -stage.stageWidth;
    // Hero flying right
    if (bgLayer1.x < -stage.stageWidth ) bgLayer1.x = 0;


    // Background 3 - Buildings
    bgLayer3.x -= Math.ceil(_speed * bgLayer3.parallaxDepth);
    // Hero flying left
    if (bgLayer3.x > 0) bgLayer3.x = -stage.stageWidth;
    // Hero flying right
    if (bgLayer3.x < -stage.stageWidth ) bgLayer3.x = 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to move the background further in a shorter period of time (which is what your scrollSpeed is changing), then you only have 2 choices:

1) Move the background area in bigger chunks (which will get the jerky effect you are describing).
2) Move in smaller chunks more often.

Given that your code is framebound the only way to move more often is to increase the framerate (which can only be done up to a point). If your app is already running below the set framerate then you would need to look at why, and what you could do to improve it (bitmap caching? Stage3D?)

After that you are into the realms of movement effects (such as motion blur) which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am doing is the first choice, but it seems to be choppy movement. As you mentioned in the second choice, I need to decrease the scrollSpeed value, and then increase the framerate. my app is running at 25fps and the scrollSpeed is 20. If I increase the framerate to 60fps and decrease the scrollSpeed to 5, the background's movement is slow. I also set CacheAsBitmap=true, but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: cacheAsBitmap will only help if your BG is vector content that can be cached (and is within certain size constraints). If your background is an image already it will make no difference. Making your project "go faster" is a different topic and would need more information. Maybe you are drawing too much, maybe over too big an area? These can often be solved with hardware acceleration using Stage3d (something like Starling might suit you), but I'm just guessing here.